# Understanding c code of microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, avr, adc, c++

I am trying to build an automatic plant watering system using ATmega16. The following is the code fragment we used:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
int adc(void);
void pump(void);
int adc_value;
int main(void)
 {
  DDRC=0x01;                          //Defining PC0 as output
  ADCSRA=0x87;                    //Setting the mode of operation
  ADMUX=0x00;                     //Selection of channel and bit alignment
  while(1)
   {
     adc_value=adc();                //reading moisture level
     pump();                               //Pump activator routine
   }
   return 0;
 }

int adc(void)
{
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result; 
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);  //what is the meaning of this line? 
   while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);  //what is the meaning of this line? 
   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);         //what is the meaning of this line?  
   return result;
 }

void pump(void)
 {
  if(adc_value>=700)                                //Pump ON trigger point
   {
     PORTC|=(1<<0);
   }
  else if(adc_value<=600)                        //Pump Off trigger point
   {
     PORTC&=~(1<<0);
   }
 }
```

In the above code, I haven't understood some lines I have commented out.Can anyone explain the meaning of those lines and why they have been used?

Comment: That code is configuring the ADC, waiting until it has done conversion, and merging some bits from one byte-wide register with some bits from another to form a wider result word.  For precise details consult the programmer's manually and/or the definition of the referenced special function registers in your platform-specific include files.

Comment: FYI This code is probably in C, not C++ (unless you are using an arduino).

Comment: You should stop and read the datasheet for this microcontroler.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);  //what is the meaning of this line?
```

Is setting two bits in the ADCSRA register (ADC Status register A). Those two bits are: ADSC (Start conversion) and ADIF (ADC Interrupt Flag, set (reads as 1) when conversion complete). The start conversion bit starts a conversion (obviously), but the ADIF bit is a little weird. It is an interrupt flag which is set (written to 1) when a conversion completes. In order to set it back to 0, a "1" needs to be written to it (this is called "write to clear"). Setting this bit in the register causes that flag to become 0.

This line:

```
while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);
```

Waits for the ADIF bit to become set again. In the previous line, you reset the flag. When the conversion completes, the flag will be set to a 1. This while loop will keep asking "hey, is the ADIF bit set?" over and over again until it becomes true. At that point, the while loop will stop and the next stuff can happen since the ADC result registers (ADCL and ADCH) are filled with the result of the conversion.

The next lines need to be considered as a block:

```
lower_bits=ADCL;
higher_bits=ADCH;
result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);
```

ADCL and ADCH are the upper and lower bytes of the ADC result. The AVR is an 8-bit microcontroller, but the result is 12 bits. The way they deal with this is to have two registers: one to represent the upper bits (bit 8 and above) and another to represent the lower bits (bits 0 to 7). The last line simply takes the upper register, shifts it over 8 places so that it is in its proper place, and sticks it together with the lower bits. The function then returns this 16 bit result (two 8-bit registers together = 16 bits).

Oh, and here is the datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf

Datasheets are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

The lines you have mentioned are some bits for ADC.

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);
```

The above line activates ADC for conversion. You might want to look into the datasheet for the specific bits `ADSC` and `ADIF`.

`while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);`

The above line waits for the ADC to convert the analog voltage into digital form; which are 8/10/16 bits depending on the resolution of ADC.

`result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);`

The above line combines the lower 8 bits and upper 8 bits to form a word(16bit)
where `(higher_bits<<8)` means he is LEFT shifting the bits so that they acquire upper 8bits of half word and then OR it with lower bits.

Now, it's your turn. Over to you.